# Apache Camel ?transacted=true

Tags: java, apache-camel, jms, activemq-classic, amqp

Hi Camel/jms developers.
Using Apache Camel amqp jms connector. And as a Broker ActiveMQ.

My configuration is quite default.

Here is a consumer code example:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    AMQPComponent amqpComponent = AMQPComponent.amqpComponent(HOST, USER, PWD);
    CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
    context.addComponent("amqp", amqpComponent);
    context.start();
    context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() {
            from("amqp:queue:1test.queue?transacted=true")
                .to("stream:out")
            .end();
        }
    });
    Thread.sleep(20*1000);
    context.stop();
}
```

Easy to see, I have configured transacted consumer. for 1test.queue.
When Im running it, in log see:

> [main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - Route: route1 started and consuming from: amqp://queue:1test.queue?transacted=true 
>   [AmqpProvider :(1):[amqp:HOST2]] INFO org.apache.qpid.jms.sasl.SaslMechanismFinder - Best match for SASL auth was: SASL-PLAIN
>   [AmqpProvider :(1):[amqp:HOST2]] INFO org.apache.qpid.jms.JmsConnection - Connection ID:...:1 connected to remote Broker: amqp:HOST2
>   [AmqpProvider :(2):[amqp:HOST2]] INFO org.apache.qpid.jms.sasl.SaslMechanismFinder - Best match for SASL auth was: SASL-PLAIN
>   [AmqpProvider :(2):[amqp:HOST2]] INFO org.apache.qpid.jms.JmsConnection - Connection ID:...:2 connected to remote Broker: amqp:HOST2
>   [AmqpProvider :(3):[amqp:HOST2]] INFO org.apache.qpid.jms.sasl.SaslMechanismFinder - Best match for SASL auth was: SASL-PLAIN
>   [AmqpProvider :(3):[amqp:HOST2]] INFO org.apache.qpid.jms.JmsConnection - Connection ID:...:3 connected to remote Broker: amqp:HOST2

If I removing ?transacted=true from consumer

> [AmqpProvider :(1):[amqp:HOST2]] INFO org.apache.qpid.jms.sasl.SaslMechanismFinder - Best match for SASL auth was: SASL-PLAIN
>   [AmqpProvider :(1):[amqp:HOST2]] INFO org.apache.qpid.jms.JmsConnection - Connection ID:...:1 connected to remote Broker: amqp:HOST2

It appears only once.

How to explain this behavior? This is normally for transacted consumers in camel?

Thank you.

P.S Checked [this topic](http://qpid.2158936.n2.nabble.com/Qpid-JMS-client-able-to-send-but-not-receive-td7635452.html) but not sure how to map it to Camel reality.

Answer (score 3):

AMQP Camel Component has not defined a pooled connection factory so it is creating a new connection for each iteration to check if there are messages in the broker.

To avoid it you should define a CachingConnectionFactory to the AMQPComponent as:

```
import org.apache.camel.component.amqp.AMQPComponent;
import org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration;

import org.apache.qpid.jms.JmsConnectionFactory;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory;

@Bean
public JmsConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory() {
    JmsConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory = new JmsConnectionFactory(brokerUser, brokerPassword, brokerUrl);

    return jmsConnectionFactory;
}

@Bean
@Primary
public CachingConnectionFactory jmsCachingConnectionFactory(JmsConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory) {
    CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory(jmsConnectionFactory);

    return cachingConnectionFactory;
}

@Bean
public JmsConfiguration jmsConfig(CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory) {
    JmsConfiguration jmsConfiguration = new JmsConfiguration();

    jmsConfiguration.setConnectionFactory(cachingConnectionFactory);
    jmsConfiguration.setCacheLevelName("CACHE_CONSUMER");

    return jmsConfiguration;
}

@Bean
public AMQPComponent amqpComponent(JmsConfiguration jmsConfiguration) {
    AMQPComponent amqpComponent = new AMQPComponent();

    amqpComponent.setConfiguration(jmsConfiguration);

    return amqpComponent;
}
```

You will get the same behavior as JMS Camel Component.

More info at [AMQP Camel Component](http://camel.apache.org/amqp.html) page

Answer (score 0):

Use jms insted of amqp.

I had similar problem. But when I use JMS instead of AMQP it worked well there was log only one time i.e single connection got created.

Seems some issue is there with AMQ component.

Thanks,
Rahul